# What is difference between WMM-PS, Power Save Poll, Power Save non-Poll, Unscheduled Automatic Power Save Delivery (U-APSD)?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, cisco-wireless

I am study on Power Save Mechanisms. Could you please show me what is difference between WMM-PS, Power Save Poll, Power Save non-Poll, Unscheduled Automatic Power Save Delivery (U-APSD)? and how to test each type of Power Save?

Thank you so much.